# catch block is returning to code inspite throw inside it c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

```
if()
{
    if()
    {
    }
    else
    {
        throw new httpexception(404,page not found);
    }
}
else
{
    throw new httpexception(404,page not found);
}
```

the inner one is throwing 404 perfectly but when control goes to outer block it is returning to the code the code above if block again and throwing 500 error, after executing so many times.

Comment: Can you explain better  "it is returning to the code again and throwing 500"?

Comment: This question is unclear. Which catch block are you talking about? And What are those if statements supposed to do?

Comment: on debugging ctrl is going back to the code written before the starting of if

Comment: i am talking about outer if,which is not going to 404 even if it is throwing 404

Comment: Which catch block, how many threads, ...

Answer (score 0):

Error code 500 is when something on your server goes wrong. What's breaking is that you throw an httpexception and don't have a try catch block to handle the thrown exception.

Try this:

```
try{
    if()
    {
        if()
        {
        }
        else
        {
            throw new httpexception(404,page not found);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new httpexception(404,page not found);
    }
catch (Exception){
// handle for when a 404 is thrown
}
```

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html

Comment: i also tried with try catch block but got the same result,the control is coming to outer else-->catch-->it comes to the code above the if condition These steps occur again and again and gives 500 error

Comment: is it inside of a loop? Please post your example using the try catch block.

Comment: try{
    if()
    {
        if()
        {
        }
        else
        {
            throw new httpexception(404,page not found);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new httpexception(404,page not found);
    }
catch (Exception e){
throw new httpexception(404,page not found);//initially tried
throw e//2nd attempt}